# Can we data refer to eventhub instances through eventhub namespaces in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, azure-eventhub, terraform-provider-azure

I have question around azurerm eventhub. Right now I am data referring to Eventhub namespace but I am unable to get the instances in the output!

```
data "azurerm_eventhub_namespace" "eventhub_namespace" {
  name  ="example"
  resource_group_name = "example resource group"
}
```

but do we have something like

```
data "azurerm_eventhub_instance" "eventhub_instace" {
  name_instance  ="example"
  resource_group_name = "example resource group"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by instance? You mean eventhubs under the namespace?

Comment: Yes to be precise I want to data refer the Eventhub's under the Eventhub namespace's and use them for IoT hub routes

Comment: If you do not have more questions and my answer solve your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm afraid you cannot do that. Terraform only expose `azurerm_eventhub_instance` in the data source. So what you want does not support by Terraform.

The possible solution is that you can use the [external data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html) to execute the script, and then use the script to get the instance in the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with these small script  to grab con string's.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
RG=$1
EVENTHUBNAMESPACE=$2
SUBSCRIPTION=$3
az eventhubs eventhub list --resource-group "$RG" --namespace-name "$EVENTHUBNAMESPACE" --subscription "$SUBSCRIPTION" > eventhub.json
eventhub=( $(jq -r '.[].name' eventhub.json) )
for eventhub in "${eventhub[@]}"; do
 az eventhubs eventhub authorization-rule keys list --resource-group "$RG"  --namespace-name "$EVENTHUBNAMESPACE" --eventhub-name "$eventhub" --name "$eventhub" --subscription "$SUBSCRIPTION" > eventhubcon.json
 arr=( $(jq -r '.primaryConnectionString' eventhubcon.json) )
  for constr in "${arr[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
  done
done
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question you asked, although it's another direction of the solution. I think my answer answered your question correctly.